Weird Debug Statement Output String not getting equal
I have this debug statement that is really weird .



Question is why did it became false? I tried doing a simple code using string x and y having the same value and doing a system debug but I can actually see it being true.
2nd Question is why on the debug that has ???1 it is just displaying the boolean value on string. Any thoughts on this?
Thank you!
EDIT:

Post the code in question. Not an image.

Hello @aSimpleRegularApexDev, The behaviour that you are presenting cannot be replicated in two systems that I attempted. Executing the following: System.debug('????1' + String.valueOf('1' == '2')); Logs the following: 18:34:50:001 USER_DEBUG (https://i.sstatic.net/Kn7PxutG.png)|DEBUG|????1false  It would be best if you can post/share entire code (not image, as Tushar said) and help us pinpoint the problem. Also, please share e

The is just an operator precedence issue, in that the + to concatenate the strings is happening before the comparison (==), which is probably how you'd want an if statement to behave, i.e.:
String firstName = 'Indiana';
String lastName = 'Jones';
String s2 = 'Indiana Jones';

if(firstName + ' ' + lastName == s2) {
  getTheSecretIdol();
}

You simply need to add some parentheses since you want to the log the result of the comparison:
system.debug('***????1**' + (integStatusOldSObject == newIntegStatusSObject));

